# stretching a layout by widest child view and match_parent second child

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to stretch layout by widest child view and match second view by parent width. In other words, combine wrap_content and match_parent.

Here's example XML(item in recycler view):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/first"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
      android:text="Loooong"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/second"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
      android:text="Short"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: example]

I tried to set match_parent to the second view in onMeasure() method, if its width is less than the first view, but when i'm scrolling the recycler_view, some views are reset back to wrap_content.

How can I achieve this behavior? Maybe constraintlayout can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set both to `match_parent`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="Loooong"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="Short"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You don't need `onMeasure`()